Existence of a sequence of disjoint measurable sets such that the measures are all positive
Let $(S,\Sigma ,\mu)$ be $\sigma $ finite measure space and $\mu$ does not concentrate on any finite sets.(For example, Lebesgue measure space.)
I want to prove the existence of $(A_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subset \Sigma$ that is disjoint sequence and $\mu(A_n)>0$ for all $n$.
How do I prove this?

It's not true without more assumptions.
For example, let $S$ be an uncountable set with the $\sigma$-algebra consisting of all sets that are either countable or co-countable (i.e. the complement of a countable set), with $\mu(A) = 1$ if $A$ is co-countable and $0$ if $A$ is countable.
This is a $\sigma$-finite measure space and not concentrated on any finite set, but there are not even two disjoint measurable sets of positive measure.

Sorry if I'm wrong, but I don't think that μ is countably additive.

It is.  See e.g. here

Wow, that’s right! This is interesting example. Thank you very much!
